# Implement pull right/left functionality

Tags: android

I want to pull my main activity right/left and show other layout there.

How this can be achieved? Thanks.

Providing screenshot from VK app.

[image]

Comment: instead of external libraries you may want to check at newly introduced navigation drawer. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: [Try This link it works for me][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586945/layout-animation-androidfacebook

or just use Action Bar library to your application http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: @ChorWaiChun, will that work for API 8?

Comment: The backward compatible library should provide this, you can get a latest version of support v4 library to try. Code documentations are here http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use the SlidingMenu open source library: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: Not enough reputation for thumbing up.